# How do I read a CSV file containing non-ASCII characters in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, csv

I am using Text::CSV to parse a csv file. Not all lines can be parsed, because of some bad characters.
The Text::CSV documentation says:

> Allowable characters within a CSV field include 0x09 (tab) and the inclusive range of 0x20 (space) through 0x7E (tilde).

How can I filter out as easy as possible any not-allowed characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of filtering out the "bad" characters, you probably want to use the [`binary`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV#binary) flag to tell [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) to stop enforcing its ASCII-only rule:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1 });
```

If you're trying to read a file that's in a non-ASCII character set (e.g. Latin-1 or UTF-8), you should look at the [Text::CSV::Encoded](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV%3a%3aEncoded) module.

Comment: +1. See, I thought that this couldn't really be a limitation of Perl's csv parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject =~ s/[^\x09\x20-\x7E]+//g;
```

will remove all those characters.

But this seems like a strange limitation on what's allowed in a CSV file. I haven't seen a csv parser yet that couldn't handle, for example, umlauts and other non-ASCII characters. I don't know Perl, though.